# Linq Except completes fast on some tables but not others

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim t1Except = t1.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().Except(t2.AsEnumerable().AsParallel(), DataRowComparer.[Default])

 If t1Except.Any() Then
     dt = t1Except.CopyToDataTable()
 Else
     dt = New DataTable
 End If
```

Executing on two tables of same structure(primary key on 1 column) contain 200,000+ rows and 100+ columns completes in a couple of seconds.  If I use same query on another two tables with same structure(primary key on 5 columns) with 350,000+ rows and 15+ columns it does not complete.

What would be occurring in the background to cause this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataRowComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907955(v=vs.110).aspx) performs value-based comparisons, so the amount of time it takes to do the comparison will be affected by performing `Equals()` checks on the actual data inside the rows.

A number of things can impact the amount of time taken by these comparisons. For example:

- some data types tend to take longer than others. Strings will typically take longer to compare than dates will.
- strings that are the same will take longer to return from `Equals()`, proportionately with how long the strings are.

So if one set of tables has a lot of the same large string values, that could be one explanation. There are a lot of possibilities, and it's hard to know for sure without knowing more about the data in the tables.

#### Update

Digging into this further: It [looks like](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8) `Except()` uses `HashSet<>()`, which will use `GetHashCode()` to achieve `O(1)` lookup times, but `DataRowComparer` [implements `GetHashCode()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowComparer.cs,3efe0bec5d6b5f86) by just looking at the first column's value.

Because the first set of tables use a single primary key, you end up with that first column producing unique hashcodes for pretty much every value. That makes lookups take `O(1)` time, which makes `Except()` take `O(n)` time.

Since the second set of tables has several columns for its primary key, I'm guessing the first column is duplicated for a lot of those rows: for each row, it will do an `Equals()` check on every row with that same first value, which will in turn do an `Equals()` check on the values in each column in the row until one doesn't match. As the number of unique values in that first row approaches `1`, the lookup complexity approaches `O(n)`, making the `Except()` call an `O(n²)` operation.

To fix this, you could implement your own `IEqualityComparer<TRow> where TRow : DataRow`, based on the `DataRowComparer` code, but which creates a hashcode based on the values in all the columns that comprise your primary key.

Another option would be to make the first row in all of your data tables be an object which includes all of your key values; an anonymous type would work well for this, since C# will auto-implement `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` for you. But this won't work if you can't change the shape of your data table.

Comment: Thank you.  That gives me a place to start looking.  I will post more about the data later.  Is there a way to avoid those issues but still find rows in x but not in y?

Comment: This was not the issue.  The two tables that compare quickly have columns that are of type char at length up to 40.   The two tables that don't complete(14 columns, mixture of dates, and char columns of length up to 9).  I use a dataAdapter.fill() to populate the tables.  Then I set the primary keys for the tables.

Comment: For every row is the Except statement looking up the matching row by dictionary in the other table?  Then doing the data row compare?  Or is it trying to spin through all the rows?

Comment: @wurzja: After digging into the .NET source code, I'm pretty sure I figured out what you're running into. See my update.

Comment: I should have looked there.  I was starting to discover that issue.  I decided to change my code to:

Comment: Great in depth answer.  I will dig into the code a little better next time.

Answer (score 0):

I changed code to not have to deal with hitting on so many rows.  I may create an IQualityComparer but for now this solves the problem.

```
Dim matchingRows As New List(Of DataRow)()
Dim comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of DataRow) = DataRowComparer.Default
Parallel.ForEach(t1.AsEnumerable(),
    Sub(r1 As DataRow)
        Dim pKey As New List(Of String)
        For Each column As DataColumn In t1.PrimaryKey
            pKey.Add(r1.Item(column.ColumnName).ToString())
        Next
        Dim foundRow As DataRow = t2.Rows.Find(pKey.ToArray)
        Dim bEqual = comparer.Equals(r1, foundRow)
        If (bEqual = True) Then
            SyncLock lockRows
                matchingRows.Add(r1)
            End SyncLock
        End If
    End Sub)
For Each item As DataRow In matchingRows
         t1.Rows.Remove(item)
Next
```